# node-mongodb findOne behavior

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a strange issue that I can't quite seem to explain.  Given the following:

```
Generics.prototype.getCollection= function(collection,callback) {
  this.db.collection(collection, function(error, document_collection) {
    if( error ) callback(error);
    else callback(null, document_collection);
  });
};

Generics.prototype.findById = function(collection, id, callback) {
    this.getCollection(collection,function(error, document_collection) {
      if( error ) callback(error)
      else {
        document_collection.findOne({_id: document_collection.db.bson_serializer.ObjectID.createFromHexString(id)}, function(error, result) {
          if( error ) callback(error)
          else callback(null, result)
        });
      }
    });
};

Generics.prototype.findOne = function(collection, _key, _value, callback) {
    this.getCollection(collection,function(error, document_collection) {
      if( error ) callback(error)
      else {
        document_collection.findOne({_key:_value}, function(error, result) {
          if( error ) callback(error)
          else callback(null, result)
        });
      }
    });
};
```

findById works like a charm.  However, findOne always returns null when executed.  I fired up node-debugger to find out what the deal was and I discovered that one of the passed variables is being destroyed/erased somehow.  _key always seems to be erased.  _value however is always there.  I tried renaming _key to something else and no matter what, it's always erased.  Any ideas as to what might be happening would be appreciated.  thanks!

***Update***
I just refactored a bit to allow for a more flexible search query and made it work with one variable.  I'd still like to know what's going on.  I feel like it's some closure business that i'm not quite understanding.

```
Generics.prototype.findOne = function(collection, searchKeys, callback) {
    this.getCollection(collection,function(error, document_collection) {
      if( error ) callback(error)
      else {
        document_collection.findOne(searchKeys, function(error, result) {
          if( error ) callback(error)
          else callback(null, result)
        });
      }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript would always treat the key of object as a string if you use the {} syntax as you did when you passed it to the findOne method:

```
{_key:_value}
```

In other words, the object above is basically treated as:

```
{ '_key': _value }
```

which I don't think is what you want. One common approach to overcome this is to create an object and use the [] operator like this:

```
var temp = {};
temp[_key] = _value; // here, the _temp symbol is interpreted as a js variable
```

Comment: that's not what I was trying to do actually, I really do want the hash as it turns out.  enclosing the key names in quotes is a habit from python :)  The question was why was the "_key" variable being nuked and the "_value" variable survived.  I wasn't able to trace through the code to find out why.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite follow your statement. What did you mean by you want the hash? And what did you mean by your habit of enclosing key in quotes (because I don't see them in your code)? To clarify my answer, var someKey = 'abcd'; var o = { someKey: 'z' }; will give you an o that is { 'someKey': 'z' } and not { 'abcd': 'z' }.